# Entity Framework code first with Access database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access, poco

Is there any way I can connect EF with an Access database using code first
so that my POCO classes can create the tables in the Access database and everything will save on that file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are out of luck, there is no EF provider for MS access (or i never heard of one exists). You could try with [ALinq](http://www.alinq.org/). It's not a EF provider, but it does provide LINQ support for MS access database. Not free a solution and I never tried it, but maybe it will work for you.